# Comparing two lists with multiple conditions in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I am trying to get a list of `User` who ARE a `FacebookFriend` and who the current user is not already following (`UserFollower`). This is the query I am trying to use, but I am still getting users who the current user is already following. Not sure what to do next.

```
 var fb = db.Members 
      .Include(i => i.User)
           .Where(x => db.FacebookFriends.Where(y => y.UserID == CurrentUserID)
                .Select(f => f.FacebookID)
                .Contains(x.ProviderUserId)
                && !db.UserFollowers
                .Select(f => f.FollowerID)
                .Contains(x.UserID)
            ).Take(6).ToList();
```

`FacebookID` is the same as `ProviderUserId`
`FollowerID` is a `UserID`

Here's the models.

```
public class FacebookFriend
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string FacebookID { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }

    public User User { get; set; }
}

public class UserFollower
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public int FollowerID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public User User { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FollowerID")]
    public User Follower { get; set; }
}
```

`Member` Table

```
[Table("webpages_OAuthMembership")]
public class OAuthMembership
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0), StringLength(30)]
    public string Provider { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1), StringLength(100)]
    public string ProviderUserId { get; set; }

    public int UserID { get; set; }

    //public User User { get; set; }
    [Column("UserID"), InverseProperty("OAuthMemberships")]
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your code *should* work, but perhaps for clarity it could be restructured using query syntax:

```
var fb =
    (from m in db.Members
     let friendIds = 
         from ff db.FacebookFriends
         where ff.UserID == CurrentUserID
         select ff.FacebookId
     let followerIds = 
         from uf db.UserFollowers
         select uf.FollowerID
     where friendIds.Contains(m.ProviderUserId) && !followerIds.Contains(m.UserID)
     select m)
    .Take(6)
    .ToList();
```